# How to group subplots by adjusting spaces in between

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have a subplots that look as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [4, 5, 6]

fig_shape, axs_shape = plt.subplots(2, 6, figsize=(6, 6))
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(6):
        axs_shape[i, j].xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
        axs_shape[i, j].yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
for i in range(6):
    axs_shape[int(i / 3), 2 * (i % 3)].plot(x, y)
    axs_shape[int(i / 3), 2 * (i % 3) + 1].plot(x, y)
```

[image]

What I want is, that the subplots are grouped in pairs of two. That means, in each row, I want plot 0 and 1 to be right next to each other (no space in between). Then a small space and followed by plot 2 and 3 right next to each other. Then a space and plot 4 and 5 right next to each other. I read, that you can adjust sizes with `.tight_layout()` and `subplots_adjust`, but I couldn't figure out a solution for this particular behavior. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use nested gridspecs:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [4, 5, 6]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5))
outer = gridspec.GridSpec(nrows=2, ncols=3)

axs = []
for row in range(2):
    for col in range(3):
        inner = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(nrows=1, ncols=2, subplot_spec=outer[row, col], wspace=0)
        axs += [plt.subplot(cell) for cell in inner]

for ax in axs:
    ax.plot(x, y)
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.set_xticks([])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: nested gridspecs]

PS: As mentioned in the other answer, matplotlib has implemented `subfigures` as a new feature. If I understand correctly, the above example would be more or less as follows:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [4, 5, 6]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5), constrained_layout=True)
subfigs = fig.subfigures(nrows=2, ncols=3, wspace=0.07)
axs = [subfig.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, gridspec_kw={'wspace': 0}) for subfig in subfigs.ravel()]

for subax in axs:
    for ax in subax:
        ax.plot(x, y)
        ax.set_yticks([])
        ax.set_xticks([])
plt.show()
```

With the current matplotlib 3.4.1, I don't seem to be able to have the inner plots without a gap.  Setting `constrained_layout=False` even makes that the 4 rightmost subplots disappear.  Now it looks like:

[image: using subfigures]

Comment: Thanks for looking at this.  Can you see if https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html#padding-and-spacing helps?